# Validation beans are not working in Java 11 and spring boot 2.5.3

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hello after spending hours reading stackoverflow answers and trying to find the answer, I'm still unable to find out why validators such as `NotNull` and `NotBlank` are not working in java. I can still send post requests with a blank name. The project is on Java 11 and Spring boot starter v2.5.3. Thank you very much in advance if you are able to figure it out, I feel I must buy you an ice cream :')

In my model:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@NotBlank
private final String name;
```

In my controller:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

    @PostMapping(path="add")
    public void addUser(@Valid @NotNull @RequestBody User user) {
        //Request body takes the data taken and converts it into a User
        userService.addUser(user);
    }

    @PutMapping(path="user/{id}")
    public void updateUser(@PathVariable("id") UUID id, @Valid @NotNull @RequestBody User userToUpdate) {
        userService.updateUser(id, userToUpdate);
    }
```

In my dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Are those really all the dependencies? Remove the `javax.validation` dependency that is already part of the `spring-boot-starter-validation` one. The `@NotNull` on your parameter in the method simply won't work (requires additional work). the one in your model (assuming it is `User`) should work.

Comment: Is your controller annotated with `@Validated`?

Comment: We are experiencing the same - SpringBoot 2.5.5 + Java 11.. validation annotations being ignored and can't see why..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I could not find out the reason. the only solution was to use older JDK. I change to JDK1.8, and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I excluded 'hibernate-validator' dependency which was coming from some other dependency (you can see this by the dependency tree) and Added these 2 dependencies and it worked fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
```